# Why does my image not pop out?

Tags: html, css, lightbox

Upon clicking the image, I want the image to pop out and show message. But i don't know how to do it.

```html
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="Images/royalpalace.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="RoyalPalace">
  <img src="Images/royalpalace.jpg" width="19.7%" height="200px">
</a>
```

Comment: Show us the code so that we can find the problem. You just gave the path of your code in the snippet.

Comment: place javascript in onload or at end of body tag

Comment: @Highdef Hi , sorry im new how do i accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to link the appropriate files in the given order:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.10.0/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.10.0/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And make sure the ***image paths are valid***.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.10.0/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.10.0/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/11/10/41/royal-palace-883800_960_720.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="RoyalPalace">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/11/10/41/royal-palace-883800_960_720.jpg" width="200px">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

First, move the `<img>` out of the `<a>` tag, or else it will redirect the user to another page, then to pop the image out, write this in a js script:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].addEventListener("click", function () { 
  this.style.display = "none";
  alert("Your message here");
})
```

You can enhance this by giving the `<img>` an id attribute and then using `document.getElementById("<Your img id>")` to access it.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with what the OP has asked. They're making use of lightbox plugin for popping up images.

Comment: Sorry, Lightbox wasn't in the tag list so i didn't realize the question was about it.

Comment: Look at the script and link tags.